# Ember controller set property in action

Tags: javascript, dom, ember.js, handlebars.js

New to ember and this is super dumb but I've wasted my day on it.

I'm creating an array of objects in my controller which i'm using to building radio buttons in my view.

when the button is clicked, i want to toggle the clicked attribute on the radio input so that it will appear clicked. Very simple but Ember keeps throwing me errors.

here's my code (edited some typos):

```
IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    radioArray : function () {
        var a = [], i = 0;
        while (a.push({ index: i++, clicked: false }), i <= 10);
        return a;
    }.property('radioArray'),

    actions : {
        assignClick : function (item, index) {
             this.toggleProperty(item.clicked);

             // some unrelated business logic here
        }
    }
});
```

this hooks up to:

```
{{#each radioArray}}
    <label {{action "assignClick" this index}}>
        <input type="radio" {{bind-attr value=index checked=clicked}} /> foo
    </label>
{{/each}}
```

All i want is to show that the correct radio button has been clicked. But when i try and set clicked to true in my ctrl, i get "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot call get with false key."

Comment: What does `toggleProperty` do? It seems like you’re missing a concept here; `radioArray` is mapping directly to a set of objects, but those objects aren’t connected to anything.

Comment: blerg. I meant this.toggleProperty(item.clicked). trying to translate from coffeescript. should then this array be a property on my model or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to use `Em.Object.toggleProperty`, then you need `Em.Object`. :)
There are functions like `Em.get` and `Em.set`, which you can use for ember and non-ember objects, but there is no function `Em.toggleProperty` for a non-ember objects.

However, you can use Em.set with Em.get to implement toggle behavior:

```
Em.set(item, 'clicked', !Em.get(item, 'clicked'));
```

P.S. Setting property dependence from property itself doesn't make sense. (I'm talking about  `radioArray : function () {...}.property('radioArray')`).

P.P.S. Working example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/memuwi/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm still getting my old error of "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot call get with false key." I'm not seeing that in your example though which is weird. However, the radio button still is not visually registering that its checked. Apparently i'm approaching this whole thing incorrectly though. Do you have a suggestion as to how i can toggle the clicked in <input type="radio" clicked /> more simply?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Using radio buttons means having a choice (one from many), but there is no multiple choice setup in template you provide (we need a radio buttons group for that: http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm).

Comment: Yes - would only want one of many. it's a rating from 1 to 10. When someone selects one of those radios, i want to add the rating to the model. that's working fine, the issue is that the button doesn't toggle